# C - Is there a more efficient way to "convert" items of an unsigned char array to an 32bit integer value? (Shared memory?)

Tags: c, arrays, shared-memory, unions

Recently I started learning C/C++ and I'm currently diving into low level programming. I found "unions" to be very interesting as I havn't seen such a behavior before to directly share memory in any language I've learned. Now I'm wondering if it is possible to improve the performance of this simple routine by using something like an Union or by *somehow* pointing the integer to a specific index of the array to get the same result as below.

```
// An Union struct which holds a 32bit integer where every of the 4 bytes can be accessed.
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char BYTE1;
        unsigned char BYTE2;
        unsigned char BYTE3;
        unsigned char BYTE4;
    } BYTES;
    unsigned long VALUE;
} UnionDWORD;

// An array of unsigned chars - representing memory
unsigned char memory[1024]; // reserving 1024 bytes of memory

// Here is where I'm wondering if the "putting together" of the 4 bytes can be improved. (Maybe a pointer to the array?)
// Return 4bytes from memory at the position "pos"
unsigned long getDWordFromMemory(unsigned long pos)
{
    // Making use of the Union struct to put the 4 bytes together
    UnionDWORD result;
    result.BYTES.BYTE4 = memory[pos];
    result.BYTES.BYTE3 = memory[pos+1];
    result.BYTES.BYTE2 = memory[pos+2];
    result.BYTES.BYTE1 = memory[pos+3];

    return result.VALUE;
}
```

Thanks a lot and I'm really sorry for my english. Unfortunately it isnt my native language.

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps you could just point with `*int` to array, the compiler will then read 4 bytes as a number instead of `1`. So that if you do `newPtr[0]` it is the 4 first 4 bytes as integer.

Comment: This is already very efficient (assuming C, not C++ so that there's no strict aliasing problems). I doubt that you could write anything better than this; the compiler should be able to recognize what's happening

Comment: C or C++, pick one.  They are not the same language.

Comment: BTW: an `unsigned long` might not be 4  `unsigned char` even though that is common.  Consider `uint32_t`

Answer (score 0):

When you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Assuming C++, this is a more correct way of doing what is probably a bad idea:

```
unsigned long getDWordFromMemory(size_t pos)
{
    unsigned char* mem = &memory[pos];
    return *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(mem);
}
```

As pointed out, the above has issues with alignment (you need to make sure pos is a multiple of 4, as `memory[0]` will be aligned correctly).  If this is a problem, then you should just use this method:

```
unsigned long getDWordFromMemory(size_t pos)
{
    unsigned long value;
    memcpy(&value, &memory[pos], sizeof(value));
    return value;
}
```

Unions can be useful, but it's usually just for packing disjoint information into smaller amounts of memory.

Comment: `unsigned long*` may have a more stringent aliment requirement than `unsigned char*`.

Comment: That's a fair point. It'll generally work correctly on modern processors misaligned, but it'll be (significantly) slower.  It's easy to check and assert or return a sentinel if that's needed.

Comment: May work on some modern processors, yet the majority of processors today are embedded small processors- billions per year - of which a large class will  bus fault on mis-alignment.